# xcode and ipad media queries

Tags: css, xcode, ipad, media

I've spent a few days tearing my hair out looking for a solution to ipad media queries with UIwebview.
I've tried device-aspect-ratio, different min / max widths or device-widths.
In Xcode the simulator or my Ipad seem to act as if they are Iphones.
A web page loaded into my domain acts correctly on the ipad.

it seems that the problem comes from xcode

i have

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width ">
```

in the html page

the css:

```
@media all
and (max-width: 667px)
{
body::before{ content: "phone fired"}
h1{
color: #F0F;
}
}

@media all
and (min-width: 768px)
and (max-width: 1024px)
{
body::before{ content: "ipad fired"}
h1{
color: #F0F;
}
}
```

If i take out min-width: 768px from the css, both Iphone and Ipad display Ipad fired, as the Iphone is within 1024px;
with min-width: 768px in place the Iphone acts correctly but the Ipad displays "phone fired". It acts as if it's width is less than 768px

Comment: Try using WURFL maybe to detect an iPhone / iPad and run separate code for it. [wurfl.js](http://web.wurfl.io)

Comment: D4Rk's answer hit it. I had the target device as Iphone, so everything behaved as iphone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. What are your targeting devices?

   - Check your settings in `Target` => `General` => `Devices`

   If you are targeting iPhone only, the app runs in `iPhone mode` on the iPad and you won't get a different `device size` here. So you'll need to select `Universal`, to natively target both.

   **This did the trick for me in my test project :-)**
2. You should also use `@media only screen` when targeting screens. This may not be an issue at all, but it is somehow more correct.
3. You should use `min-device-width` instead of `min-width`, when checking for the with of the device.

Let me know if, this does not help you. Then I'll check out some more stuff.

Comment: It's sooo easy when you know how. That didi it. Thank you.

Comment: `device-width`, `device-height`, `min-device-width`, `min-device-height`, `max-device-width` and `max-device-height` have all been depreciated in favor of `width`, `height`, `min-width`, `min-height`, `max-width` and `max-height`. The depreciated expressions might still work in some browsers and on some devices but their use is discouraged. [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries]